# The monster truck hit the red car? Is this correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, verbs

I am playing toy vehicles with my kid but sometimes I am not sure if my English is correct. I would like to know which one is correct. Let's say I am intentionally making a monster truck bump another car, what would be the correct phrase?

- Oh no, the monster truck hit the red car.
- Oh no, the monster truck bumped the red car.
- Oh no, the monster truck bumped into the red car.
- Oh no, the monster truck crashed into the red car.

Answer (score 1):

All fine. It doesn't matter much which one you choose.

"Bumped" sounds like it is fairly harmless, use this for a sensitive child who may be upset by car crashes.

"Crashed" sounds dramatic. Use this for a child who would be bored by mild play and wants something more exciting.

Of course, if the child doesn't speak English, then it matters even less!

Comment: I've been teaching my kid English (not perfect though). So is "the monster truck hit the red car" more like a natural sentence a local English-speaking adult would say?